# Heroku - Can I call Maven from Procfile?

Tags: deployment, maven, heroku

I'm investigating Heroku as a platform and am trying to get a basic Java webapp to run on it.  The webapp already builds and runs with Maven (using Tomcat and the cargo-maven-plugin), so I figured this should be a breeze given that Heroku uses Maven to manage its installation/deployment tasks.

That's not the case however, as I'm unable to get the thing to actually start up.  My `Procfile` has the following in it:

```
web: sh ./startServer-heroku.sh
```

And the `startServer-heroku.sh` is just:

```
mvn clean install cargo:start -Dcargo.maven.wait=true
```

This works fine when I test locally using the `foreman start` command, as described in the Heroku tutorial docs.  But when I try it on the actual Heroku server, I get the following log messages:

```
2011-11-09T02:30:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting 
2011-11-09T02:30:27+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished 
2011-11-09T02:30:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh ./startServer-heroku.sh` 
2011-11-09T02:30:33+00:00 app[web.1]: ./startServer-heroku.sh: 1: mvn: not found 
2011-11-09T02:30:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited 
2011-11-09T02:30:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

It appears that `mvn` is nowhere to be found on the system's `PATH`, so the command is failing.

Is it possible to invoke `mvn` from the Heroku `Procfile`?  And is there anywhere that has a definitive list of commands that are and are not available from the `Procfile`?

Comment: take a look at [jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin/index.html), which automate the entire deployment process to Heroku. maybe it will help in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James's answer provides good instructions for getting Jetty to work on Heroku, and his comment includes a link to a good reference on using embedded Tomcat.  But it is also possible to run the standard, standalone version of Tomcat on Heroku.  Here's how I was able to get it to work:

First, set up your POM to install and configure Tomcat as part of your build, and also to deploy your application to the installed Tomcat instance:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.18/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.18.zip</url>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>standalone</type>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId>com.yourcompany.name</groupId>
                            <artifactId>yourArtifact</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <properties>
                                <context>ROOT</context>
                            </properties>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                        <goal>configure</goal>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Next, create a trimmed-down `server.xml` file that will work on Heroku:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<Server port="-1"> 
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" /> 
    <Service name="Catalina"> 
        <Connector port="${http.port}" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"/> 
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost"> 
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/> 
        </Engine> 
    </Service> 
</Server>
```

...this is necessary because your Heroku app is only allowed to bind to a single port (which changes each time a new instance is created, and is specified in the `$PORT` environment variable).  Attempting to bind to any other port will crash your app.  As the port is dynamic, it must be passed to `server.xml` via the `http.port` system property, but we'll get to that later.

While you're at it, also create a `persistence.xml` file that will work with Heroku:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="quiz_devel">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show.sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/> 
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="10"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="40"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1"/> 
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="30"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Note that there is no `hibernate.connection.url` specified here.  This is because Heroku specifies the database url that your app should use in the `$DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

Now it's time to create a simple shell script that configures the environment and sets everything up so that Tomcat can actually run:

```
#point to the correct configuration and webapp
CATALINA_BASE=`pwd`/target/cargo/configurations/tomcat6x
export CATALINA_BASE

#copy over the Heroku config files
cp ./server-heroku.xml ./target/cargo/configurations/tomcat6x/conf/server.xml
cp ./persistence-heroku.xml ./target/cargo/configurations/tomcat6x/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml

#make the Tomcat scripts executable
chmod a+x ./target/cargo/installs/apache-tomcat-6.0.18/apache-tomcat-6.0.18/bin/*.sh

#set the correct port and database settings
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dhttp.port=$PORT -Dhibernate.connection.url=$DATABASE_URL"
export JAVA_OPTS

#start Tomcat
./target/cargo/installs/apache-tomcat-6.0.18/apache-tomcat-6.0.18/bin/catalina.sh run
```

This is doing a number of things:

1. It tells Tomcat to use the configuration and deployment artifacts that cargo packaged as part of your build, by setting `CATALINE_BASE` to point at the correct place.
2. It overwrites the default `server.xml` and `persistence.xml` files with their heroku-specific variants.
3. It marks all the startup scripts in the Tomcat instance that cargo installed as part of the build as executable.
4. It specifies values for `http.port` and `hibernate.connection.url` based upon the environment variables provided by the Heroku platform.
5. Finally, it runs Tomcat.  Note that you cannot use `startup.sh` to do this, as `startup.sh` will launch Tomcat in a new process and then terminate.  Heroku doesn't understand this, and thinks that the termination of `startup.sh` is the termination of the Tomcat process.

Finally, the last step is to set up your `Procfile` to call your startup script, something along the lines of:

```
web: sh startServer-heroku.sh
```

With this approach you can have a project that is compatible with Heroku, while still retaining its ability to run standalone as a standard Java webapp.

Answer (score 7):

Maven is not in the slug that gets deployed to dynos.  It's only available at compile time.  One option for dealing with this is to use the `appassembler-maven-plugin` and `jar` packaging to generate a start script:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory> 
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>foo.Main</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then the `Procfile` would be:

```
web: sh target/bin/webapp
```

Another option is the `maven-dependency-plugin` and `war` packaging:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>7.5.3.v20111011</version>
                                <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

With a `Procfile` of:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, though your example is using Jetty.  Do you know if it's possible to do a comparable thing with Tomcat?

Comment: Tomcat doesn't have the equivalent of jetty-runner, but you can still deploy with Tomcat in a couple of ways. One is using embedded Tomcat. Check this article which was just posted: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call maven from your Procfile.

To do so you need to include maven in your slug by making a small modification to the 'compile' script in the java build pack as described in the [README.md file from the "heroku-buildpack-java" project](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java/blob/master/README.md):

> For example if you want to have maven available to use at runtime in your application you simply have to copy it from the cache directory to the build directory by adding the following lines to the compile script:

```
for DIR in ".m2" ".maven" ; do
 cp -r $CACHE_DIR/$DIR $BUILD_DIR/$DIR
done
```

I [added these lines](https://github.com/stianl/heroku-buildpack-java/commit/b379cbabcc6b580b9aa085f303a502021659ac4d#diff-c7b43338c09c3c9afd420fd8b6bb5198) right after maven download, and before changing to BUILD_DIR.

In your Procfile you can then call .maven/bin/mvn

If you are building an artifact (war/jar) that you can run from java or in a servlet container, then you should probably do something along the way of the other answers, but if you really need to run maven, then this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

As @stian said you can call maven in Procfile. To do this you need to update the java buildpack (compile) with the above lines. I updated the current java buildpack with these lines and created this repo. So, you can use it.

https://github.com/erdemkiiliic/heroku-buildpack-java

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).